# Location path in applicationhost.config not mapping to assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I'm having a strange issue with an C# ASP.NET WebAPI project where the `<location path="example.namespace.webapi">` attribute value in `applicationhost.config` is not mapping to the fully qualified name of the assembly; instead it's tagging `"(1)"` on the end.

Thus, when I try to change the IISExpress configuration manually, my changes are ignored.

**./.vs/applicationhost.config**:

```
<location path="example.namespace.webapi">
    <!-- VS2015/IIS is ignoring this section -->
    ...
</location>

<location path="example.namespace.webapi(1)">
    <!-- VS2015/IIS creates and uses this section -->
    ...
</location>
```

I've tried deleting both `<location>` sections, and forcing VS2015 to regenerate the configuration by changing the `Anonymous Authentication` property value, but it simply creates the location path with a `(1)`, even when the proper section doesn't exist.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: how are you editing the `application.config` file , using `NotePad++` ?

Comment: Yes, though I'm pretty sure it doesn't create a lock on the file

Comment: what i'm saying when ever you are trying to change it with notepad ++ it would be storing to 32bit, using  default will be stored in 64 bit ..

Comment: check [this](http://www.beacontechnologies.com/blog/2014/06/why-are-changes-to-my-applicaionhost-config-not-showing-up-in-iis/) link for more details

Comment: location path is not assembly name, it's a path (sitename, site application, virtual directory, physical directory, etc.): https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/deep-dive-into-iis-configuration-with-iis-7-and-iis-8 (search 'location tags')

Comment: @SimonMourier Does that apply with IIS Express also? If indeed it is a path, I can't locate one anywhere with the suffix "(1)". There must be a mapping back to my project somewhere.

Comment: @Webruster Thanks but I don't think the 32/64bit issue applies in this scenario as the `applicationhost.config` file is within the `.vs` directory within my solution.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Yes, its not actually cause, but i have given that way because you mentioned in your qst that you are unable to apply the changes to the `application.config` for that this may be a reson  i assume..

Comment: @ChrisPickford - yes, it's also for IIS express

Comment: @SimonMourier - No path exists with the name `example.namespace.webapi(1)` on my filesystem. Somehow it's resolving back to a project in my solution but I can't work out how/why.

Comment: @ChrisPickford - like I said and like it's documented, it's not always stricly speaking a *physical* path.

Answer (score -1):

You could be conflicting with something in the master IISExpress config(s). Have a look in:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config
```

Comment: What might be conflicting with my project name? The only location in both of these files is `<location path="" overrideMode="Allow">`.